# mouseout not fired when hovered element gets covered by another element

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I recently discovered a strange behavior with the `mouseout` event in JavaScript.
Please see my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Uf3xQ/25/

When I hover over the button, the `mouseenter` event is fired. When I leave the button, the `mouseout` event is fired. So far so good.

Now when I hover, then click and the click event shows a div which is placed over the button, the `mouseout` event will also be fired.

But when the div is showed after a short delay using `setTimeout` for example, the mouseout event won't be fired until I move the mouse.

Can you explain this behavior to me?

**UPDATE:**
I submitted the bug to chromium and they confirmed it. See here: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=159389

The bug also occurs in Opera, Safari (WebKit in common) and IE

Comment: This seems a cornercase bug of mouseout implementation..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I browsed WebKit bugzilla and https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=4117 appears to be your bug, you should add a new comment to the bug with a link to your testcase, as the testcases linked in the bug seem to be lost (404 error).

Answer (score 4):

Try using delegate on the overlay to bubble the event up.
**EDIT**
Fiddle is being slow today and the fiddle I had originally posted didn't have the snipped of code that I used.

this DOES work in fiddle with jQuery version (1.8.2) selected
link to jsBIN fork : http://jsbin.com/ugeniq/3/edit

**EDIT 2**
I just realized that the mouse/over/out without the div didn't work. I've updated the code so now it works with and without the div overlay.

```
var fail = true;

var button = document.getElementById("button");
var overlay = document.getElementById("overlay");
var log = document.getElementById("log");


button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    if (fail) {

        // mouseout won't be fired until you move the mouse
        window.setTimeout(function() {
            overlay.style.display = 'block';
        }, 0);

    } else {

        // mouseout event is fired instantly
        overlay.style.display = 'block';

    }


    log.innerHTML += 'over' + "<br>";

}, false);

button.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
    log.innerHTML += 'over' + "<br>";
}, false);

button.addEventListener('mouseout', function() {
    log.innerHTML += 'out' + "<br>";
}, false);

$(overlay).delegate(button, 'mouseover', function() {
        log.innerHTML += 'over' + "<br>";
});

$(overlay).delegate(button, 'mouseout', function() {
        log.innerHTML += 'out' + "<br>";
    });
```

Comment: @JulianHollmann I added the entire snippet. The fiddle fork I linked to didn't have the proper code.

Comment: @JulianHollmann I made another update to the code to fix both situations (div overlay hidden/visible). Please try.

Comment: Now the div also triggers the event, which is not intended, right?

Comment: You tell me. I thought your issue was that the event didn't bubble up? is that not the issue?

Comment: The problem is, that the mouseout event on the button is not triggered. It turned out to be a bug in some browsers.

Answer (score 2):

It appears to be an obscure browser bug (in `Chrome`). `Firefox` seems to be working fine. I'm not sure about other browsers.

I replaced everything with native js, to make it clearer:

http://jsfiddle.net/qLCY3/4/

Comment: Same "bug" in IE9, Opera and Safari.
I'm really interested in the story behind this behavior.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to solve this problem is to wrap the button and overlay and change the mouseover and mouseleave to this wrapper.

//HTML

```
<div class="helper">
  <div class="overlay"></div>
  <button class="button">Foo</button>
</div>
```

// JS

```
var fail = true;
$$('.helper').addEvent('mouseover', function() {
    console.log('over');
});

$$('.helper').addEvent('mouseleave', function() {
    console.log('out');
});

$$('.button').addEvent('click', function() {
    if(fail) {

        // mouseout won't be fired until you move the mouse
        window.setTimeout(function() {
            $$('.overlay').setStyle('display','block');
        }, 0);

    } else {

        // mouseout event is fired instantly
        $$('.overlay').setStyle('display','block');

    }
});
```

Comment: The overlay seems to be arbitrary. What if there was another DIV over the helper?

Comment: I use the helper div just to avoid mouseout events for the inner HTML. That means you can do inside the div what ever you want without loosing the mouseover effect. You can wrap as much as you want arround the helper div. It will does not have side effects

Answer (score 1):

just mouse out event the overlay and make it fade out or whatever you want it to do. I made it Alert in your fiddle try it out.

```
  $$('.button').addEvent('mouseover', function() {
console.log('over');
```

});

```
  $$('.overlay').addEvent('mouseout', function() {
   alert("ee");
```

});